# tomcat pool not resetting the pool. Getting too many connections error

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat pool on tomcat 6. Following is the my resource definition:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/DBConnectionFactory"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="root"
         password="root"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="600"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sicad?autoReconnect=true"
               minIdle="3"
       maxActive="250"
       testWhileIdle="true"
       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            maxIdle="10"
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="10000"
              maxWait="-1"
     />
```

Now, ideally after going to 250 connections all the idle connections should be removed, or atleast by some means mysql should not give too many connections error. Also, please note that if i do showprocesslist, there are hardly any concurrent queries going on. So i was thinking that timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis should do the trick of removing idle connections and keep the pool alive. but as soon as 250 connections are set, the mysql starts throwing too many connections error. I was expecting that the tomcat pool, would remove any idle connections off the pool to keep the pool size reasonable. also note that its not that there are so many being created.

What's worse, this same configuration is working on developer machines and staging server + test server, but not on product server. also all the machines are clones of each other. i have rebooted machine, re-installed mysql, everything but all in vain.

Comment: Do you close connections after use in the `finally` block of the very same `try` block as where you're getting a connection from the `DataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked, finally abandoned the hardware and same codebase, driver and mysql installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did configure this on a global or application level? Check out [4 Mistakes To Avoid On Apache Tomcat](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/08/03/4-mistakes-avoid-apache-tomcat) by Mark Thomas on how putting the `context.xml` in the wrong place can create more connections than you intend to. Long story short:

- if you configure the pool in the global `context.xml` you get a pool per application
- if you configure the pool in the application `context.xml` you get only one pool
- if you want to have a global pool shared between applications you have to use [resource links](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Links)

Comment: this should not be the problem here because i have just one web app thats using DB.